# Help identifying a book about a planet with a regent who could kill via a wireless signal to a brain implant

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I think it was a three-book saga, in the first one there was an ongoing invasion of a race of creatures who kidnapped women for breeding, but there was a regent or magistrate who nobody knew, who dismissed the menace of these creatures and could kill anyone who opposed his opinion with a killswitch signal because I think everybody had a brain implant.

The hero was able to indentify this regent and after removing it he organized an army of "free men" (brain implant removed) to combat these creatures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not a brain implant but a "torc", an explosive neck ring. It's [Jack Vance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Vance)'s [*Durdane* trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durdane_series): [*The Anome*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1230) (aka *The Faceless Man*), [*The Brave Free Men*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2318), and [*The Asutra*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1231).

Comment: WOW, that was fast! I tried googling with several "key" words to no avail, thank you very much!